# what is Javascript .map equivalent in vb?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to make a simple script in vb that will transform a string "These are my characters" into this "tHeSe ArE mY cHaRaCtErS"

It seemed simple at first, I created a userform and with 2 textboxes (input and output) and a button.
I wanted to split the string into characters firist then alternate between using UCase and LCase with the helf of Mod2 and a loop.

I asked my friend for how would he do it in his preferred language he gave me this in javascript

```
string.split('').map((c,i) => (i%2)? c.toUppercase() : c.toLowercase() )
```

and this in ruby

```
string.split('').each_with_index.map 
{ |c, i| return c.uppercase if (i%2).zero? Else c.downcase}.join ''
```

That's when I thought that .map function is way easier for splitting a string and performing operation on each one.

So my question how would I go about replacing .map used in those languages in VB?
thank you in advance.

Comment: [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also known as LINQ Select.

Comment: @KennethK. - Slightly expanded, that's an *answer*, not a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the `Select` method, for further info please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq).

In order you use this method, you have to add the following statement at the beginning of your source code file:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

In this namespace many [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods) on `IEnumerable(Of T)` are defined. One of them is the Select method. Since `String` implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)` these methods can be also applied to a `String`. `Select` can be used for projecting the elements of a sequence of items as you do so in other languages using `map`.

e.g. (courtesy of [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) - check comments)

```
New String(s.Select(Function(c, i) If(i Mod 2 = 0, Char.ToLower(c), Char.ToUpper(c))).ToArray())
```

Comment: Alright I guess that answers my question, I'll look into the select method and try to implement it into my script. Thank you for you help

Comment: @AndrewMorton oh thank you for the helpful reply. I wanted to ask for an example but I didn't want to ask too much. this is very useful

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks I included your example in the answer !